# Places API Corridor - 403 Error

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to use the corridor function through the places api and I'm getting a 403 forbidden error.

`{
  status: 403,
  message: "appId doesn't have permissions required for this endpoint /browse/by-corridor"
}`

How do I go about getting authenticated, I can't find any areas in the Dashboard to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The end point /browser/ is a premium end point which according to [documenation](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics_api/entrypoint-maturity-availability.html) can only be enabled by getting in touch with HERE sales representative.

Use this link to contact [sales](https://developer.here.com/contact-us)